# Getting error message: “Pixel Launcher APK 7.1.1 The package appears to be corrupt"

Tags: android, apk, pixel, android-launcher

I perviously installed pixel apk 7.1.1 on my Samsung galaxy s8 and it was fine.I recently restored my handset to factory setting now when I'm trying to reinstall the APK in getting this eror message:

> The package appears to be corrupt

Does anyone know why this is and if so is there a way around this issue?

Comment: This looks like an off-topic question, there is no relation to programming.

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm new to all of this.